# Extracting objects out of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to map from this:

```
companies: {
  apples: {
   Q7: {
    price: 1,
   },
   Q6: {
    price: 1,
   },
  peaches: {
   Q7: {
    price: 1,
   },
   Q6: {
    price: 1,
   },
 },
};
```

to this:

```
{ "companies": {
    "apples": [
        {
            "name": "Q7",
            "price": 1
        },{
            "name": "Q6",
            "price": 1
        }
    ],
    "peaches": [
        {
            "name": "Q7",
            "price": 1
        },{
            "name": "Q6",
            "price": 1
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

How I am trying to achieve this: 
I have a selector which gives me the `companies` object and then I map over it and assemble my object but I don't get it quite right.

This is my function:

```
const weaponProducts = Object.entries(getCompanies(state)).map(([companyType, companies]) => {
        const prod = Object.entries(companies).map(([key, companies]) => {
           return {
               name: key,
               price: companies.price
           }
        });
        return {
            [companyType]: prod
        };
    });
```

getCompanies(state) returns the following object:

```
{
    "companies": {
        "apples": {
            "Q7": {
                "price": 1
            },
            "Q6": {
                "price": 1
            }
        },
        "peaches": {
            "Q7": {
                "price": 1
            },
            "Q6": {
                "price": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result of the function is the following. But as explained I want it to look like the second code section of my post.

```
[
  {
    "apples": [
      {
        "name": "Q7",
        "price": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "Q6",
        "price": 1
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "peaches": [
      {
        "name": "Q7",
        "price": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "Q6",
        "price": 1
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Actually if the result shown here is the result of the function, it works correctly. The second `companies` which u asked to create will break the code cause there is an object without key and with values. I'm not sure if this make sense for you

Comment: I edited the post above. The last code section of my post is the actual return value of the function. But I dont want it to be like that. Can you please tell me what to adjust in my function in order to make it look like in the second code section.

Comment: your second output doesn't look like valid JSON

Comment: Yea sure just first can you post what this `Object.entries(getCompanies(state))` gives you back?

Comment: This is the output of the function Halil: https://jsonblob.com/64de82a7-aa9e-11ea-a88a-4ff68eaea4eb

Comment: I adjusted the outputs. Sorry, I thought it would be still somehow understandable. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: just to confirm, you want to keep the companies key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also take `entries` and then `map` the objects accordingly.

```js
var companies = { apples: { Q7: { price: 1, }, Q6: { price: 1, }, }, peaches: { Q7: { price: 1, }, Q6: { price: 1, } }};

const result = (inputObj) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(inputObj).map(([key, obj]) => [
      key,
      Object.entries(obj).map(([name, val]) => ({ name, ...val })),
    ])
  );

console.log(result(companies));
```

Comment: This is even a more elegant solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

since your desired output is an object, not an array, you should use `reduce` instead of `map`:

```js
let companies = {
  apples: {
   Q7: {
    price: 1,
   },
   Q6: {
    price: 1,
   },
  },
  peaches: {
   Q7: {
    price: 1,
   },
   Q6: {
    price: 1,
   },
 },
}

let fruit = Object.keys(companies)
let output = fruit.reduce((output, currentFruit) => {
  output[currentFruit] = Object.keys(companies[currentFruit]).map(q => {
    return { name: q, price: companies[currentFruit][q].price }
  })
  return output
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

(I think there was a syntax error in your companies object, I corrected in the snippet)

Answer (score 0):

If you're down to try something new, here's a different way to express the desired transformation using a library I authored.

```js
const x = { companies: { apples: { Q7: { price: 1, }, Q6: { price: 1, }, }, peaches: { Q7: { price: 1, }, Q6: { price: 1, }, }, } }

const { pipe, fork, map, tap, get } = rubico

const y = map(map(pipe([
  Object.entries,
  map(fork({
    name: get(0),
    price: get([1, 'price']),
  })),
])))(x)

console.log(JSON.stringify(y, null, 2))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rubico/index.js"></script>
```